# How to display p tag and input on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My current code is :

```
<div class="row" id="loginForm">
        <p>Username : </p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input" id="usr">
</div>
```

This shows the input box in the next line, how can i display the p tag and the input box on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bootstrap form-horizontal

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usr">Username:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input" id="usr">
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 8):

Paragraphs are usually displayed as a block of their own.

While you can change the styling of it to change that, what you have is not a paragraph, so you shouldn't mark it up with the `p` element.

Use [a `label` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) instead. Aside from being the correct markup, it is an inline element so will render on the same line by default.

```html
<div class="row" id="loginForm">
        <label for="usr">Username : </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input" id="usr">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`display: inline-block` is your friend:

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="loginForm">
  <p>Username:</p>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input" id="usr">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *table* without border. So it looks very tasteful and easy.

```
<div class="row" id="loginForm">
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td><p>Username : </p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control input" id="usr"></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't 1997. We have CSS now. https://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your input into  tag so you don't need to use `for` attribute.

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="loginForm">
    <label
        >Username : 
        <input type="text" class="form-control input" id="usr">
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    display: block;
}
label > p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file, as a barebones solution,

```css
p{
  display: inline;
 }
```

It's good practice to not use

in this scenario but  as others as said, but this is the most barebones way to answer your specific question if you were hardstuck on using

for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

You could just use a span tag,

```
    <div class="row" id="loginForm">
    <p>Username : <span><input type="text" class="form-control input" id="usr"></span></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

with boostrap you only add class form-horizontal and this work for you